# Does the C++ Standard Library prohibit non-standard iterator categories?

Tags: c++, iterator

The following program, which creates a user-defined iterator category tag, is rejected by clang (using `-stdlib=libc++`), but not by other compilers and standard library implementations:

```
#include <iterator>

struct my_iterator_tag {};

struct my_iterator : std::iterator<my_iterator_tag, int> {};

int main()
{
  std::iterator_traits<my_iterator>::value_type x;
  return 0;
}
```

It's not clear to me whether or not the C++ standard prohibits instantiating `std::iterator_traits` with an iterator type that has a non-standard iterator category.

Is this program illegal?

clang's output (when using libc++) is below:

```
$ clang -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp 
test.cpp:9:38: error: no type named 'value_type' in 'std::__1::iterator_traits<my_iterator>'
  std::iterator_traits<my_iterator>::value_type x;
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 2):

The `std::iterator` template is defined as follows:

```
template<class Category, class T, class Distance = ptrdiff_t,
    class Pointer = T*, class Reference = T&> struct iterator {
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef Distance difference_type;
    typedef Pointer pointer;
    typedef Reference reference;
    typedef Category iterator_category;
  };
}
```

I can't see anything wrong with your declaration of:

```
struct my_iterator : std::iterator<my_iterator_tag, int> {};
```

So, loosely speaking, you end up defining:

```
struct my_iterator {

    // ...

    typedef Category my_iterator_tag;

    // ...
};
```

Can't see anything wrong with that. It's a valid declaration.

Now, let's take a look at the definition of `iterator_traits`:

```
template<class Iterator> struct iterator_traits {
   typedef typename Iterator::difference_type difference_type;
   typedef typename Iterator::value_type value_type;
   typedef typename Iterator::pointer pointer;
   typedef typename Iterator::reference reference;
   typedef typename Iterator::iterator_category iterator_category;
};
```

Applying this template to an `Iterator` of `my_iterator`, I don't see anything technically wrong here, either. The above definitions of these templates are lifted straight from the standard. So, as far as the actual strict, literal declaration of these templates in the C++11 standard, I see nothing wrong with the declarations.

The C++ standard, of course, defines five standard iterator categories, so as far as the rest of the C++ library, it would be necessary to analyze that further. I suppose that various things like iterator adaptors will probably be undefined behavior, with anything other than the five standard iterator categories.

I couldn't find, with a cursory look, anything that explicitly states that using anything other than the five predefined tags with `std::iterator` and `std::iterator_traits` is undefined behavior, so in this limited example only, I'd say this is technically valid, even though it's of dubious value.